# Problem with Ubuntu and eth0 interface

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, iptables, interface

I have a problem that I cannot access a web page when using eth0 interface. If I use loopback interface everything works fine.

wget http: //127.0.0.1:8080/app - works ok
wget http: //192.168.50.129:8080/app - connection refused.

I'm doing this on the same machine.

Any ideas what might be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should check the `Listen` directive in your server configuration

```
   Listen 8080
```

should listen on all interfaces, port 8080.

In doubt you can specify several times the same directives

```
  Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
  Listen 192.168.50.129:8080
```

and restart the server.

If your firewall drops the packets, you wouldn't have `connection refused`, so I think it is more a web server configuration problem.

---

If you are using **nginx** and not apache, check your `server` section(s) and the same remark applies

```
  listen 8080;
```

or

```
  listen 127.0.0.1:8080;
  listen 192.168.50.129:8080;
```

Comment: This most likely is the problem.... But I still have to figure out how to make a service listen on some other interface. I need to make Oracle 10g XE listen on that interface.

Answer (score 2):

First check if  your webserver is listening on eth0 and not just lo

$ netstat -ntlp

If that is okay then do a telnet on port 8080 to see if the port is open.

$ telnet 192.168.50.129 8080

If the telnet doesn't work check your firewall rules.

$ iptables -L -n

Answer (score 0):

It could be that you have a

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

in your */etc/apache2/ports.conf*?

Or a

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:8080>
```

under your sites configuration (usually */etc/apache2/sites-available/default* or analogue)